# How does the Manjaro release cycle work?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation, manjaro

I am wondering how the Manjaro release cycle fits in with it being a rolling release.

Comment: It isn't a rolling release.

Comment: @jasonwryan Manjaro is a rolling release. It is always up to date unless the new package instability

Comment: No: certain packages are "held back" for security reasons; that isn't a rolling release...

Comment: @jasonwryan just because some packages are held back does not make it not a rolling release. A rolling release is a release not based on stagnant package versions. This question received a down vote do you have any suggestions to improve it?

Comment: @jasonwryan according to the [Manjaro WIki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/The_Rolling_Release_Development_Model) page, it is indeed a rolling release: *"However, **Manjaro uses a Rolling Release Development Model**, whereby rather than being replaced, the same core system will instead be continually updated and upgraded. As such it is not, nor will it ever be, necessary to re-install a later release of Manjaro in order to enjoy the very latest and most up-to-date system possible."*

Comment: @terdon you are free to believe whatever their wiki tells you...

Comment: @jasonwryan lol. If it were anyone but our resident Arch expert, I would indeed believe their Wiki. Seing as it's you, should I assume the Wiki is wrong?

Comment: @terdon no: I am just being grouchy. Technically, you don't need (or shouldn't) to reinstall, but holding back packages, [like this](https://lists.manjaro.org/pipermail/manjaro-general/Week-of-Mon-20151130/000277.html), isn't rolling with upstream, IMO.

Comment: @jasonwryan I am curious why holding back packages makes it not rolling as apposed to rolling with some packages held back?

Comment: You don't see how those terms are mutually exclusive: "holding back" and "rolling"?

Comment: @jasonwryan Arch holds back package versions just for development. Gnome only has ever other version on the Arch repo. The only difference is the gnome team decided to only release every other version instead of the Manjaro team.

Comment: No, you are wrong. If upstream releases a *stable* version, it is pushed to the Arch repos.

Comment: @jasonwryan OK I think I get where you are coming from; if the upstream group in charge of the package pushes a package release they say is stable in your opinion it has to be added to the repo for the distribution to be rolling?

Comment: Yes: that is the point, to roll with upstream. Otherwise, you are just doing some version of point releases, snapshots, whatever you want to call them...

Comment: @jasonwryan OK. I am not sure I agree with you but it's good to know where you make the distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I found was this from [Manjaro wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/The_Rolling_Release_Development_Model)

> These releases are more accurately new snapshots of the Manjaro system. Just like photographs, these snapshots are in essence images that portray the Manjaro system at a particular point in its development. As such, one purpose they serve is to help the developers to both chart and evaluate the continued development of the Manjaro system, as it is of course easier to pick up on the finer details from a single image than from a moving picture.
>   Furthermore, due to being in a beta stage of development, Manjaro is evolving at a very rapid pace. Existing users may themselves have noticed how frequently new software updates and upgrades have become available, and how much the system has changed in only a few months. As a consequence, a snapshot of the Manjaro system --again rather like a photograph-- will very quickly become out of date. New snapshots are therefore released in order to make life easier for new users, who may otherwise be faced with the prospect of downloading huge volumes of new software packages to update and upgrade their newly installed systems from an older ISO.
>   Where these snapshots most obviously differ is in the choice of pre-installed software applications provided, as well as other smaller tweaks such as the default theme(s) used; however, the core Manjaro system running underneath is the same and any applications added or removed from a particular snapshot can also be added or removed from an existing installation. And, of course, users will tweak and customise their own systems in accordance with their own personal preferences and tastes, anyway. Again, irrespective of whatever release of Manjaro has been installed, provided it is kept up to date, then that will be the latest version available.